# How to create CakePHP Pages

Tags: cakephp

I'm wanting to create a series of pages using CakePHP. I know you can simply create a view inside the pages folder but what if I wanted to build hierarchical pages like: /legal/policy/

Also if for example I wanted /legal/ to not exist ie. act only as a prefix how would I also do that?

So two questions:

1.) How to create hierarchical pages
2.) How to create prefixes like /legal/ so domain.com/legal would throw 404 but domain.com/legal/policy would show a page

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is handled by routing in CakePHP.  Check in the manual under the Pages section.

Basically, you're going to create a Route similar to as follows, in routes.php:

```
Router::connect( '/legal/:page', array( 'controller' => 'pages' /* or other controllers */, 'action' => 'display'), array( 'pass' => array( 'page' ) );
```

That will connect /legal/* to PagesController::display( $page = null ), with the first parameter (after "legal/") passed as $page.

That answers #1.

For #2, I would recommend just checking to see if $page is null.  If it is, then you're at the root for that route (/legal/).  Just do a redirect inside your PagesController over to your 404 page from there.

Comment: How do I choose which pages have the /legal though?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Any URI accessed that begins with /legal/ will be routed to the PagesController::display() method, with the :page (part after /legal/) passed as a parameter to the display() method.  You'll want to manually call the Controller::render() method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your view in the following:

```
/app/views/pages/legal/policy.ctp
```

It would then be accessible via: www.example.com/pages/legal/policy

If you want to remove the /pages/ from the URL then use routing as Travis Leleu suggests.